# how to set values to rows of boolean filtered dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to set the values of "FreeSec" column to `True` for the filtered rows of my pandas dataframe. Here is the code:

```
data[data["Brand"].isin(group_clients)].FreeSec = True
```

However, when I check the values they are still set to `False`.

```
>>> data[data["Brand"].isin(group_clients)].FreeSec

12     False
163    False
164    False
165    False
166    False
167    False
168    False
169    False
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use loc to do this **without chaining**, which will garauntee that assignment works:

```
data.loc[data["Brand"].isin(group_clients), "FreeSec"] = True
```

*Assignment in loc is overridden so that the implementation detail of whether it's actually [a view or a copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) doesn't matter, it does matter if you chain so avoid/be very careful.*

Comment: messed up with useful and accepted ticks! thats "to be fair" i accepted one while usefulled another o_O

Comment: Don't know what's useful, but you can upvote more than one answer :)

Answer (score 2):

It works other way around:

```
data["FreeSec"][data["Brand"].isin(group_clients)] = True
```

I'm not an expert in Pandas, so have to check why is it working like this.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: Returning a view versus a copy issue. thnx a lot!

Comment: Thanks, was almost sure that OP one returns copy, but didn't know about exact rules