# Check if an element in a list exist in a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe where each row contains s&p stocks for each month end. I want to perform element-wise check to see if each element in the unique_stock_list (numpy array) I created on the side exists in the "tickers" column for the same end of month date. And if it exists, I want it to return true and populate another empty dataframe I created where each row is a month end date and column names are from the `unique_stock_list`.

```
final['tickers']
1596    [A, AABA, AAPL, ABC, ABT, ACS, ADBE, ADI, ADM,...
1603    [A, AABA, AAPL, ABC, ABT, ACS, ADBE, ADI, ADM,...
1614    [A, AABA, AAPL, ABC, ABT, ADBE, ADI, ADM, ADP,...
1626    [A, AABA, AAPL, ABC, ABT, ADBE, ADI, ADM, ADP,...
1632    [A, AABA, AAPL, ABC, ABT, ADBE, ADI, ADM, ADP,...
             
unique_stock_list
array(['A', 'AABA', 'AAL', 'AAP', 'AAPL', 'ABBV', 'ABC', 'ABMD','ABT'...
```

The empty dataframe DF_Matrix looks like this:

```
            A   AABA AAPL ABC ABT                                                           
2009-12-31  NaN  NaN NaN    NaN NaN ...

2010-01-31  NaN  NaN    NaN NaN NaN ...
```

Comment: please, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497054/how-to-set-values-to-rows-of-boolean-filtered-dataframe-column or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64486467/setting-column-to-true-false-based-on-comparison-of-two-other-columns-in-pandas, or try to edit the question, adding part of the code in order to be reproduced

Comment: Why is this in pandas at all?  Pandas is not helping you in the slightest.  Why not just a list of lists, which is simple and straightforward to handle.  And there's nothing `num` in your `numpy` array.  Text processing is not a strength of either pandas or numpy.  And what does 1596 mean in terms of a date?

Comment: Continuing off of what @TimRoberts said, maybe a dictionary of dates where the value is a set containing the stocks might be a better data structure.

Comment: What do you want to populate the output dataframe with?  If you want it to be `True/False` for whether the stock appears in the month, you could use something like the following: `pd.get_dummies(final.set_index("date")["tickers"].explode()).groupby(level=0).agg("sum").reindex(unique_stock_list, axis=1).fillna(0).astype(bool)`.

Comment: In `final`, where is the month-end defined? Is it encoded in e.g. 1596 - if so, how?